# CodeIgniter Unset A Signle Session Item In An Multidimensional Array

Tags: codeigniter

On my User.php library in my login function I create admin sessions by

```
$create_session = array(
    'is_logged' => true,
   'user_id' => $row->user_id
);

$this->CI->session->set_userdata('admin', $create_session);
```

The issue is when I try to unset admin session data individually it does not unset the session I select.

Var Dump:

```
Array
(
    [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1449906266
    [admin] => Array
        (
            [is_logged] => 1
            [user_id] => 1
        )

)
```

**Logout function on library:**

Does not Unset: Preferred Way

```
public function logout() {
    $user_data = $this->CI->session->userdata('admin');
    unset($user_data['is_logged']);
    unset($user_data['user_id']);
}
```

But when I use this way below it works

```
public function logout() {
    $this->CI->session->unset_userdata('admin');
}
```

For some reason will not let me unset session data individually from an array in sessions.

> **Question** How am I able to unset codeigniter session data individually that are in my admin session array?

Full User.php library

```
<?php

class User {

    private $user_id;
    private $username;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
        $this->CI->load->library('session');
    }

    public function login() {
        if ($this->validate_password() == true) {

            $this->CI->db->select('*');
            $this->CI->db->from($this->CI->db->dbprefix . 'user');
            $this->CI->db->where('username', $this->CI->input->post('username'));
            $query = $this->CI->db->get();

            if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {

                $row = $query->row();

                $create_session = array(
                    'is_logged' => true,
                    'user_id' => $row->user_id
                );

                $this->CI->session->set_userdata('admin', $create_session);

                $this->user_id = $row->user_id;
                $this->user_group_id = $row->user_group_id;
                $this->username = $row->username;

                return true;

            } else {

                return false;

            }

        }
    }

    public function is_logged() {
        $get_session = $this->CI->session->userdata('admin');
        return $get_session['is_logged'];
    }

    public function logout() {
        $user_data = $this->CI->session->userdata('admin');
        unset($user_data['is_logged']);
        unset($user_data['user_id']);

    }

    public function validate_password() {
        if (password_verify($this->CI->input->post('password'), $this->stored_hash())) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function stored_hash() {
        $this->CI->db->where('username', $this->CI->input->post('username'));
        $query = $this->CI->db->get($this->CI->db->dbprefix . 'user');
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            $row = $query->row();
            return $row->password;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}
```

Note:

I have two lots of sessions one admin for back end and catalog for front end that's why in array.

Comment: On a sidenote, your `is_logged()` function may cause a Notice error, 'Notice: Undefined index: is_logged'. You could use `return (array_key_exists('is_logged', $get_session) && $get_session['is_logged'] === true);` to ensure the array key exists, and return a boolean based on its existence and value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `unset()` by itself will not remove the values from the CodeIgniter session. You would need to save those changes to the session using `$this->CI->session->userdata('admin', $user_data)` again.

For example:

```
<?php
$user_data = $this->CI->session->userdata('admin');

print_r($user_data);
// Shows: Array ( [is_logged] => 1 [user_id] => 123 )

unset($user_data['is_logged']);
unset($user_data['user_id']);

print_r($user_data);
// Shows: Array ( )

// Check what values are saved in the session:
print_r($this->CI->session->userdata('admin'));
// Shows: Array ( [is_logged] => 1 [user_id] => 123 )

// Save your changes to the session 
$this->CI->session->set_userdata('admin', $user_data);

// Check what values are saved in the session (now that we've updated the session)
print_r($this->CI->session->userdata('admin'));
// Shows: Array ( )
```

So, you need to do the following steps to update arrays stored in your session:

1. Get values from session: `$arr = userdata('userdata')`
2. Remove value(s) from array: `unset($arr['key'])`
3. Save changes to session: `set_userdata('userdata', $arr)`

As a workaround, you may be able to edit the `$_SESSION` directly, bypassing the CodeIgniter's [Session library](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/libraries/Session/Session.php#L717):

```
unset($_SESSION['admin']['is_logged']);
unset($_SESSION['admin']['user_id']);
```

I wouldn't advise bypassing the Session library like this, but it might suit your purposes more than the steps I've listed above.

Comment: Thanks for your advice I have found the way to unset a single session item that is in an array. I have added a answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [@Kirk Beard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/248567/kirk-beard)  for advice I have found way to use CodeIgniter session and unset individually data that is in side my admin array();

I create the admin multidimensional array session

```
$create_session = array(
   'is_logged' => true,
   'other_item' => 'something'
);

$this->session->set_userdata('admin', $create_session);
```

Then if you need to unset a single item in the admin array.

```
unset($this->session->userdata['admin']['is_logged']);
```

Works for me.

To get multidimensional array session.

```
echo $this->session->userdata['admin']['is_logged'];
```

Or

```
$userdata = $this->session->userdata('admin');
echo $userdata['user_id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Generate sessions as `$this->CI->session->set_userdata($create_session);` instead of `$this->CI->session->set_userdata('admin',$create_session);`

such as

```
$create_session = array(
    'is_logged' => true,
    'user_id' => $row->user_id
);

$this->CI->session->set_userdata($create_session);
```

Now unset by name even individually

```
 $this->CI->session->unset_userdata('is_logged');
 $this->CI->session->unset_userdata('user_id');
```

Comment: I have two lots of sessions one admin for back end and catalog for front end that's why in array.

Comment: no problem. If you need to destroy entire session together then you can use `$this->CI->session->unset_userdata($create_session);`

Comment: I need to be able to unset them individually because I will be adding more session data that does not need to be unset.

Comment: I have found the way in my answer thanks for your time.